# Batch file for printing text file to virtual port

Tags: windows-7, usb, printer, batch-file

How can I write a batch file for printing a text file to a dot matrix printer?
The printer is connected to the system using USB and the port is the USB002 virtual port.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: using windows 7 OS

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work with DOS programs, for example, you first need to share the printer. After, type: `net use LPT1 \\\\yourcomputersname\printername /PERSISTENT:YES`. Then you could do something like `copy C:\path\to\file LPT1`.

Comment: Try this instead since it's a basic text file: `start /min notepad /P <filename>` this prints to the default printer.

Comment: I updated my answer with a different method that we actually use on older SATO printers (parallel, but the process works the same way).

Comment: I can't really explain it much more. What OS is this? Does the printer work just printing basic text with notepad?

Comment: Printing with DOS is very very limited in terms of what you can do with it. I'll leave this question to someone who may have done this before.

Comment: As the OP mentioned before your last comment, he's using Win7.

Comment: @Karan I realize that, but printing with the command prompt is basically printing within the limits of DOS.

Comment: Depends. Many people say "batch file" because that's all they've ever heard of, but a PowerShell or WScript solution that can be invoked from the command-line would be equally acceptable. Let's see what the OP says.

Comment: i need solution for print text file with my content only and the printer is connected to usb002 virtual port