# how to print DOS output to virtual port printer?

Tags: windows, printing, cmd.exe

I write the text file into DOS using TYPE [filename.txt] and now i want to print the output of TYPE DOS command into dot matrix printer which connected in USB port(virtual Port)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file for printing text file to virtual port](http://superuser.com/questions/609941/batch-file-for-printing-text-file-to-virtual-port). If you need to add more detail or clarify something, edit your existing question instead of posting a new one.

Comment: I suspect this is a windows cmd and not a dos question.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to share the printer. Then use this following batch code:

```
type filename.txt > \\computername\sharedprintername
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use > command.

Im using dotmatrix usb printer and virtual port management.

ex: echo QWERTY > com1 (in case, virtual port installed as com1).